# What is "ios" in the Ruby documentation for puts?

Tags: ruby, puts

iOS has cluttered up getting good search results for this question. [The Ruby docs for `puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) say that it

> writes the given object(s) to ios.

What is "ios". My best guess is that it is "input/output stream" but not sure if that makes sense or not.

Comment: Your guess is right, and it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is absolutely right. Here is a paragraph in which both terms `ios` and `I/O streams` are used: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-close
I hope you find that helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It is whatever you're calling `puts` on:

```
$stderr.puts("Hello from Standard Error") # $stderr is IO
puts("Hello from Kernel") # main is IO
File.new("/tmp/foo").puts("bar") # File is IO
```

Anything that inherits from `IO` (or `Kernel`) will respond to `puts`.

```
$stderr.class.ancestors # => [IO, File::Constants, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
self.class.ancestors # => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
File.ancestors # => [File, IO, File::Constants, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```